# Very easy question about infinitesimals

Tags: limits, exponential-function

how can I prove that:
    $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = 0 ? $$
I suppose that the exponential "goes" to $0$ faster than linear, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try translating it to $y={1\over x}$ and $y\to\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$, then $y \to +\infty $, when $x \to 0$
$$
\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}}{x} = \sqrt{y}e^{-y}
$$

Comment: I solve the limit, but I would understand how can I say: "this limit is 0, because of.." with the infinitive rules

Comment: Just make sure you remember to convert your equation back into terms of $x$ toward the end.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, your limit goes to $\infty$, since $1/x^2$ is very big whenever $x$ approaches zero. A very different story would be if you had to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}.
$$

Comment: oh, I made a mistake writing formula, I edited my question.